# Setting a binding property in a derived class is not firing the property changed in the class it derives from

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created this class:

```
public partial class ScrollHeadingView : ContentPage
{
    Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView scrollView;

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsScrollableProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsScrollable), typeof(bool),   
        typeof(ScrollHeadingView), false, propertyChanged: OnIsScrollablePropertyChanged);

    public bool IsScrollable
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsScrollableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsScrollableProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnIsScrollablePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = (ScrollHeadingView)bindable;
        if ((bool)newValue)
        {
            view.scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical;
            view.scrollView.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Always;
        }
        else
        {
            view.scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Neither;
            view.scrollView.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Never;
        }
    }
```

When I use the class like this then the OnIsScrollablePropertyChanged is not being called. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<t:ScrollHeadingView
    x:Class="Test.DecksTabPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    IsScrollable = "False" >


public partial class DecksTabPage : ScrollHeadingView
{
    public DecksTabViewModel vm;
    public DecksTabPage()
    {
        BindingContext = vm = new DecksTabViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        vm.OnAppearing();
    }

}
```

Here I have added a debug point, but it's never reached:

```
var view = (ScrollHeadingView)bindable;
```

Comment: You could post the code in xaml so that we can check the issue .

Comment: Just to double check, have you tried setting `IsScrollable="True"`? Does your breakpoint hit then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the `IsScrollable` property to `false` then you `OnIsScrollablePropertyChanged` will not be called because the default value for your property is `false` and therefore hasn't changed. To prove this point you can try setting the property to `true` and you should see that your breakpoint now hits.

The best approach here would be to set defaults for your `false` condition. Something like in your constructor:

```
public ScrollHeadingView()
{
    view.scrollView.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Neither;
    view.scrollView.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Never;
}
```

Comment: I am still looking into it but it seems likely.  Just clearing up some other problems and then I will go back and look into detail.  Thanks